# Traveling to Europe on UK biometric resident permit (BRP)

Tags: uk-visa, schengen, indian-citizens

Can an Indian national working in UK on Tier 4 general visa use the biometric resident permit (BRP) card to travel to European (Schengen) countries without applying for a separate visa?

Comment: Does https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77159/can-you-enter-the-schengen-area-with-a-uk-visa help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, since an Indian citizen needs a Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area, you are still required to get a visa.

Only **residence permits** of a Schengen country can be used as a visa *replacement* when visiting another Schengen country (togeather with the passport).

Your UK residence permit allows you to apply for a Schengen Visa from within the United Kingdom and must be valid for at least three months longer than intended return date (the same rule applies for your passport).

---

**Sources**:

- [German Embassy, London: What documents do I need?](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/visa/short-stay-schengen-visa/what-documents-do-i-need?openAccordionId=item-2303528-1-panel)